# Getting Premature end of file Exception

Tags: java, parsing, xhtml, jsoup

I'm trying to parse the existing xhtml file to add the additional body content into that file. I am using the following code:

First I am reading  the body from the Jsoup and i am trying to put it in  the XhtmlFile

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(readFile, "UTF-8");
            Elements content = doc.getElementsByTag("body");

            try {
                 Document document=null;
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                // Create the builder and parse the file
                document = (Document)factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(finalFile);
                //document.getElementsByTagName("body")append(content.toString());              
                //document=parserXML(finalFile);                
                document.getElementsByTag("body").append(content.toString());

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("SAXException>>>>>>");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                System.out.println("in  parser configuration Exception block>>>>>>");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But i am getting the following exception:

```
[Fatal Error] ResultParsedFile.html:1:1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.converter.typeconverter.EmailTypeConverter.readHTML(EmailTypeConverter.java:101)
    at com.converter.typeconverter.EmailTypeConverter.callTika(EmailTypeConverter.java:64)
    at com.converter.master.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:64)
```

Plese help me in solving this issue ...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sounds like finalFile probably isn't a valid XML file...

Comment: If it's XHTML, you should be able to parse it with a plain XML parser. Jsoup is not especially aimed at broken !X!HTML.

Comment: @Jon means i may not use DOM or SAX parsers to parse, but from jsoup i am getting the body content of the html file which i need, i just want inject that message into the body of the xhtml(finalfile).thanks for your time. Any pointer in this regard..

Comment: @ramesh: But you're trying to *parse* `finalFile` before you do anything with `content`. If that's not already a valid XML file, you'll have a problem...

Comment: @Jon: So i want to first append the content to the finalFile before doing the parsing.

Comment: @ramesh: Are you expecting `finalFile` to be empty before you start then? It's really not at all clear what's going on...

Comment: Is the EmailConverter some third party library ? Is there any '@' character somewhere at in-appropriate place in XML ?

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error at the first position of the file (which the 1:1 indicates) it means that the file is empty.

Maybe you start reading the file before the source has closed it?

In case you use an input stream (which is not the case here), this can happen when you re-use a stream that you have already used to reach the end of the file. You need to create a new stream from the input file in order to reset it from the start of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that you have a badly formed XML file. Usually when I've gotten this message I had an opening tag with no matching end tag. I think you'll also get this on an empty file.

Comment: I m using xhtml file, in which i want add some body part. but the skeleton xhtml page with proper opening and closing tags are available.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently experienced this error, turns out one of my .hbm.xml files was being generated as empty, error was being generated from application context xml which was referring to the hbm file

Answer (score 0):

1.xml is not readable.
2.To rectify the xml ,only  option is to drag and drop into spreadsheet,error will be highlighted more clear.after doing suggested correction xml will finally be loaded to spreadsheet.then that xml which is successfully loaded will not face any parsing issue